# Priority of Close Votes

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens if a fifth person chooses a different reason to close?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32700/what-happens-if-a-fifth-person-chooses-a-different-reason-to-close)

Is there priority of Close Votes' reasons?

I've noticed that **subjective and argumentative** has more priority than **exact duplicate** on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274937/code-readability-vs-conciseness), each of them had same 2 votes (I've voted as **too localized** for 5th vote)

How about others? It will be good to know priority of those too.

```
"id":1,"name":"exact duplicate"
"id":2,"name":"not programming related"
"id":3,"name":"subjective and argumentative"
"id":4,"name":"not a real question"
"id":7,"name":"too localized"
"id":104,"name":"belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com"
"id":102,"name":"belongs on serverfault.com",
"id":103,"name":"belongs on superuser.com"
```

**UPDATE**:

I've participated in close as exact duplicate, but please just don't delete it, this one has proper answer to reference later on

Comment: Perhaps the 2 'exact dup' votes point to different dup posts and the priority got splitted. :P

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32700/what-happens-if-a-fifth-person-chooses-a-different-reason-to-close

Comment: @random, the answer is random? are you sure?

Comment: When the votes are split, first one selected is what's chosen.

Comment: @S.Mark, not random but 1st come 1st serve I think

Comment: Imm, its kind of mysterious then, I can't know which one was first selected.

Comment: Since it was closed as subjective and argumentative, that was the first chosen.

Comment: I'm also participating in close as exact duplicate, but please *just* don't delete it, this one has proper answer to reference later on.

Comment: Meta dupes are hardly ever deleted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The last vote cast has priority in the case of tiebreakers. Has nothing to do with the ID numbers in the table.

Comment: Ok, that make sense, and the mystery got cleared :-) thanks Jeff

Answer (score -2):

Well, of course Exact Duplicate isn't chosen as much as 'Subjective and Argumentative'...

You have to click type in the ID of the question  that you think it is a duplicate of.

**AKA:**

It's more work....

<sup>This has been a public service announcement by the LPA (Lazy Programmer Association)</sup>

Comment: Ermm, the OP already said each has 2 votes

Comment: I've rephased, I voted as **too localized** for 5th vote.

Comment: Am I the only one who searches to find a *different* duplicate than the one(s) already selected? You guys are all fat slobs.

Comment: Not as lazy as Downvoter who votes whatever because he's too lazy to select a dupe already selected: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39632/easier-to-close-questions-as-a-duplicate/39634#39634 @eth

Comment: It's less work than you think: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21826/greasemonkey-easier-vote-to-close-for-duplicates