# How SO handles close reason on equal number of Close votes different catagories

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “closed” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question)
>   [What happens if a fifth person chooses a different reason to close?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32700/what-happens-if-a-fifth-person-chooses-a-different-reason-to-close)
>   [Priority of Close Votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39658/priority-of-close-votes)

When a question is closed! It will highlight the reason for closure (ie, based on the maximum number of votes for a category is received)

considering the example below: if a question has received two close votes for being off-topic, two as well for not being a not-a-real question. Also someONE found it to be too-localized!

With total number of 5 close votes, question will be closed. But since both the number of off-topic votes and not-a-real question votes are equal ie 2. What will be the reason highlighted on the question after getting closed. Does it depend on the reputation of close voters?

like `if (total reputation of close voters for off-topic > total reputation of close voters for not-real-question)
then close question as off-topic`

This scenario ideally shouldn't happen! But if it happens then how it is handled and is this how it works?

> two users have voted for off-topic and two for not-real .. the last
>   person chose too-localized. Then what will be the close reason?

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32700/what-happens-if-a-fifth-person-chooses-a-different-reason-to-close/32701#32701

Comment: @MartijnPieters, like I have mentioned in the example, there can be tie, 2-1-2

Comment: @Bart, let me ask this, two users have voted for `off-topic` and two for `not-real` .. the last person chose `too-localized`. Then what will be the close reason?

Comment: @Mat, ohk if you find it a duplicate question then what is the answer for my question? asked just above this comment also in question added as blockquote!

Comment: Did you read the **What if multiple close reasons are used on a question?** part of that question I linked?

Comment: yes I read, that goes by last vote, but here in my question last vote was on `too-localized`, ie, neither on `off-topic` nor on `not-a-real`

Comment: Too localized isn't part of the tie.

Comment: now it is clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last vote cast for the reason have equal votes has priority in the case of tiebreakers.

And in the case of different reasons chosen, the first selected will be the one that triumphs.

> two users have voted for off-topic and two for not-real .. the last
>   person chose too-localized. Then what will be the close reason?

result will the last vote cast for off-topic or not-real and too-localized has not significance until it reach two votes.