# Capitalize "possible" in the automatically inserted comments when you vote to close as a dupe

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments

The comment reads:

> possible duplicate of [link]

The missing capitalization bothers me a lot; it should be **P**ossible.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44528/going-to-tell-one-way-or-the-other

Comment: actually i'd rather not see them capitalized.  for as much text as they have it's not necessary, and comments already feel informal.

Comment: I hate it when someone posts using my name... I hate this feabug!

Comment: @Downvoter, couldn't agree more. Also, if it's going to look like it came from me, it damn well better be written correctly.

Comment: I've just reached the threshold to mark questions as duplicates, but I don't think I really want to do it now that I'm automatically attributed with poor grammar.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `status-complete` now, since the current format is capitalized?

Comment: Don't you just hate it when a presumable 1-line 'safe' change gets greatly upvoted by the community, but declined? It doesn't do much for my faith in the voting system on Meta. @MyNameIsNotMcThomasJohannson Based on a possible duplicate comment an hour ago, it doesn't look changed to me (unless it was changed back).

Comment: [This has been changed now.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307037/capitalize-possible-duplicate-of-x-properly)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

down with capitalism!

[image: To Serve and Correct - Grammar Police]

Comment: I have, quite possibly, more fun on meta than I ought to have.

Comment: possible duplicate of [meta.stackoverflow.com/a/44530/155641](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44530/155641)

Comment: This is "funny" and all, but it's not an answer. Yes, I know this is very old, but it still reflects poorly on the quality of MSE. Not to mention the blatant offensiveness about calling people with a certain political ideology "pigs".

Comment: @TheforestofReinstateMonica If it ain't woke, fix it 'till it is. I realize this 11 year old joke could be considered offensive, though paired with the opposing post I made (which has fewer votes) it should be clear that it's a pair of answers with no content to allow meta users to vote on one option or the other, since that's what this question is about. Nevertheless, I'll remove the word "pigs" since it's a very loaded term, and by so doing it attacks the idea, not people who believe it.  I hope this is woke enough for Meta to leave it, however I welcome delete votes by anyone who hates fun.

Answer (score 31):

Obviously this is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), so everyone should just accept the judgment passed down from on high, but to further elaborate a bit of why people might be bothered...

Bad punctuation/grammar/spelling is one thing when someone else does it, it's entirely another when it's attributed to you.

if jeff wants to rite liek this on his site thats his perogative.

If words are going to be automatically attributed to me, I don't want them to reflect badly on me.

If capitalizing a single letter is too hard, having the Community user be the comment owner would make this far less obnoxious.

Comment: Obviously, the system doesn't care about proper grammar.  Oh wait: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94370/what-are-your-quality-standards-and-how-do-you-meet-them

Comment: that's* by the way. I agree with this answer.

Comment: @crush Exactly! I produce my own errors.  I don't need any extras!

Comment: I agree. I just voted to close a question as a duplicate (first time I've done that), and the lowercase "p" reflects poorly on me. It should be a capital "P". Why is this even an issue? Just fix the stupid thing so it doesn't make people look bad who are trying to help.

Answer (score 20):

Seriously, you don't even need to *do* anything other than add *one* CSS rule:

```
span.comment-copy:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

How is that such a big deal, from the Stack Exchange network that features, among others, '[English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/)' and '[Writers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/)' and was (at least *partially*) meant to **['*trick* [us] into becoming...better writers if that's what it takes](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/02/how-to-write-without-writing.html)**<sup>1</sup> (emphasis Jeff's)?

If you're going to attribute words to us, or put our names on auto-generated comments, then follow the technical specifications of the language in which you're writing, I don't care whether, or not, this comment meets the syntactic and grammatical requirements of a sentence, it really is *close enough* that capitalisation should be the default.

And, frankly, not-capitalising means I have to waste my time editing a wrongly-capitalised auto-generated comment; if I'm doing that I'd rather not have the auto-comment, since it saves me precisely *no time* and increases general irritation.

...this has, clearly, been bugging me for a while. Please reconsider the [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined); I really don't see any significant cost attached to making this request, instead, [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

---

1. Though the prior assertion about having us 'write without writing' is, in this case, rather more literal than I suspect was ever intended.

Comment: Though I'd also prefer the upper case P, using CSS to achieve that doesn't feel right to me either.

Comment: Agreed; but if the problem was the amount of work/team-involvement required to implement an upper-cased first-letter this seemed to be the absolute *easiest* means I could think of (though, honestly, I have no idea how changing `possible` to `Possible` could involve *less* work than a simple database query or template-edit...).

Comment: I'm sure changing it would have been less time spent than answering/declining this (and duplicate) questions. So I assume implementation effort is not the issue here...

Comment: I hadn't considered it that way, to be honest; but if not *implementation-effort* it suggests a far less...rational/considered resistance to the request. Which seems a little, and I hate to use the word since I'm no longer an infant, *unfair*. (Not to mention slightly silly.)

Comment: What about the exceptions, like [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)?

Answer (score 18):

<del>Maybe someone should run a query on the data dump to see whether uppercase or lowercase is more common for the first character of a comment. My suspicion is that lowercase is more common.</del>

**Update**: As [balpha](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha) indicated in a comment, upper-case is far more common:

> From the SO March data dump (with the crippled comments, but statistically it should be okay): 1,934,139 comments total, 1,425,013 (73.68%) start with an uppercase letter, 247,919 (12.82%) with a lowercase letter, and 261,207 (13.51%) don't start with a letter at all.

Comment: From the SO March data dump (with the crippled comments, but statistically it should be okay): 1,934,139 comments total, 1,425,013 (73.68%) start with an uppercase letter, 247,919 (12.82%) with a lowercase letter, and 261,207 (13.51%) don't start with a letter at all.

Comment: In That Case, We All Need To Help Offset This Growing Problem By Capitalizing **Every** Word Of Our Comments.

Comment: UsErs shOULd jUst cOntInUE UsIng thE sAmE cAsE As thEy hAvE ALwAys bEEn sIncE thEy ArE OnLy cOmmEnts

Comment: CamelCaseIsTheWayToGoBecauseAllThoseSpaceCharactersTakeAwayValuableSpaceFromThe600CharLimit

Comment: @balpha - you might need to skip past the username if the comment starts with an @...

Comment: @balpha: And most of the ones which don't start with a letter probably start with "+1" or "-1". Don't know if it's worth it at this point.

Comment: @Pollyanna, @mmyers: Even if all 13.51% no-letter-on-start comments could be argued to fall into the lowercase category, that would still leave us with a 74/26 split und thus the point remains: "Uppercase is more common." That's why I don't think it's worth to start special-casing.

Comment: @balpha - I actually agree with the OP - the capitalization should be corrected, regardless of the precedence.  I expect that once you get past the usernames and other non alphabetic characters the incidence of uppercase will likely be higher than 74%.  Note also that the OP is voted higher than my funny "against" post.  I doubt there are many that actually want it to be lowercase.  (but then I'm constantly surprised by people here, so....)

Answer (score 16):

This Is A Capital Idea!

Comment: Anyone opposing should be subject to capital punishment. Defining "capital punishment" in this context is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 8):

I posted this as suggestion / feature request [on Meta.SO, yesterday](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307037/capitalize-possible-duplicate-of-x-properly).

> This will be fixed as of build 3735 (on MSE/MSO) and build 2858 (on other sites).
>   ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307114/1835379))

So, as of those revisions, the feature request is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)!

Answer (score -52):

It's not a complete sentence, so it doesn't need to be capitalized. We don't capitalize the tabs on the user page, or the homepage, for example.. or, heck, even here on the question page itself.

Comment: wHY WOULD IT BE SUCH A BIG PROBLEM TO CAPITALIZE THE THING? iT'S NOT THAT HARD AND IT WOULD LOOK BETTER.

Comment: That case, add the words "This is a" and hey presto, a real sentence.

Comment: @Farseeker don't be ridiculous. That's way too complicated!

Comment: A sentence ("a string of words", so the one word tabs don't apply) must always be capitalized, "complete" or not (why is it not complete?).

Comment: Incredible response.

Comment: @Justin Satyr Even if this post would have a thousand down votes Jeff would still not care so it doesn't really matter…

Comment: this answer is not useful (btw.: Headlines aren't whole sentences, but capitalized too).

Comment: Arguing that punctuation doesn't matter because it's ungrammatical... I'm not sure that's going to mollify anyone bothered by this.

Comment: Is the company's name officially "stack exchange inc."? Does the company use lowercase letters for its name in its legal documents?

Comment: @pacoverflow You'll be pleased to know this has been fixed long ago, also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243913/13 ;-)