# Tag badges render incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I have just noticed that the tag badges have the correct colour border but not the correct background. [tag badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have new special styles for tag-based badges.

They are much harder to get than almost every other badge, and have a different "flavor" than regular badges, so they need to have a distinctive style.

Comment: Ok. IMHO it doesn't look quite right, but as I don't have any better suggestions I am in no position to complain.

Comment: Perhaps a paler grey background rather than white?

Comment: sure, if someone has a mockup of a badge visual that works, I'll be happy to include it. The goal is for tag-based badges to *look* distinct (because they are), but still be recognizable as a badge.

Comment: They already have a distinct style. None of them start with capital letters.

Comment: @jon way too subtle. Look at the badge list on the user page now and it's clear which are tag badges -- and these badges are quite an accomplishment, look how few even exist on SF after a whole year!

Comment: It hovers darkgrey which makes text hard to read. Is this intentional? I'd say, make the hover lightgrey.

Comment: @Jeff: I was kinda serious, kinda [not serious](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44528/capitalize-possible-in-the-automatically-inserted-comments-when-you-vote-to-clo).

Answer (score 7):

It's hard to strike a balance between text readability and medallion visibility, but I tried two different shades of gray.  I prefer the lighter background.

[image: background #a5a5a5]

[image: background #e1e1e1]

One other thing that I noticed is that when you hover over the badges, the background changes to a dark gray, and the text is no longer readable.  The text should change to white/light gray on hover, or the background shade should be lighter.

[image: badge hover]

Comment: I'll second the lighter gray background instead of the white.

Comment: Seems to be fixed already :)