# tag-badge design broken

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, badges, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tag badges render incorrectly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50063/tag-badges-render-incorrectly)

[I got blinded. http://img375.imageshack.us/img375/9893/screenshot20100517at125.png](http://img375.imageshack.us/img375/9893/screenshot20100517at125.png)

[Cheese. http://img532.imageshack.us/img532/2358/screenshot20100517at143.png](http://img532.imageshack.us/img532/2358/screenshot20100517at143.png)

(OSX, FF3.6.3 & Safari)

Comment: A picture says more than 1000 words!

Comment: duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50063/tag-badges-render-incorrectly ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50063/tag-badges-render-incorrectly).

Answer (score 2):

I bet that this is [status-bydesign] so as to be able to distinguish tag badges from regular badges.