# The "possible duplicate..." auto comment should have an upper case "P"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close, automatic-comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capitalize “possible” in the automatically inserted comments when you vote to close as a dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44528/capitalize-possible-in-the-automatically-inserted-comments-when-you-vote-to-clo)

The auto comment that is inserted on the users behalf when voting to close as a duplicate starts with a lower case 'p'.

Perhaps this is being slightly pedantic, but it's the start of a sentence so should begin with an upper case letter.

Answer (score -2):

It wouldn't follow the rest of the feel of the site if they did that. For example:[image]

All of those items are in lower case. It appears the only things they keep in upper case are headings and buttons.

It appears [Jeff Atwood agrees with me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44528/capitalize-possible-in-the-automatically-inserted-comments-when-you-vote-to-clo/47209#47209) (although he wrote his response first), Cue the Downvotes!

Comment: Those are not user input (nor posted on behalf of a user), so I guess [different statistics apply](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44528/capitalize-possible-in-the-automatically-inserted-comments-when-you-vote-to-clo/44553#44553)?