# Feature: a nice way to discourage frequently asked and just as frequently dismissed questions

Tags: feature-request

There are some particular questions that are asked at least once a day on Stack Overflow.

They're well-posed questions about trying to solve problems nobody should solve (great example: "How do I get this HTML DOM element with regular expressions?").

Obviously, all the interaction will be in the comments — since you have to be evil to actually answer such questions.

So, here is a nice idea: let the Ajax interface that suggests related questions be more aggressive if some particular phrases (in this case, the combination "regex, HTML, element") are typed. As in, display a highlighted sentence on top of the similar questions with some specific information (in this case, something along the lines of: "Are you going to ask how to parse HTML with regex? Don't. Click **here** instead.").

I think it would be a useful feature, from which both the asker's reputation and the quality of the posts would benefit.

---

Edit: I see there is a similar feature for questions that might be too subjective on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq), so implementation should be a breeze.

Comment: @RedDwight, thanks a lot for your corrections and sorry for the poor grammar/syntax/x. I didn't sleep for the last 36 hours, and I didn't check it before posting since I was talking with a friend - this is meant to be an admission of guilt, not a defense.

Comment: [Obviously](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44528/capitalize-possible-in-the-automatically-inserted-comments-when-you-vote-to-close), @RedDwight, the messages *would* be all-lowercase! ;-)

Comment: It seems that @RegDwight suffers from a similar name confusion that "jinguy" does, hehe.

Comment: @Grace: indeed, this is not the first time, and not even the twenty-first. I've even considered changing my screen name, people would probably have less trouble spelling "Sir Elton Hercules John, CBE".

Comment: It's particularly ironic to get it wrong while thanking @RegDwight for having improved my spelling.