# Downloading OpenSTV doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, broken-link

Trying to download OpenSTV from https://stackoverflow.com/election/2 doesn't work for me.

Clicking the Windows link redirects me to https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/election/download-openstv with a picture of a cute cat trying to fix the problem.

Comment: You should be able to get OpenSTV from [here](http://www.openstv.org/), but yeah I can repro the link being broken.

Comment: @CodyGray How do I download it without paying for it? :P

Comment: Oh, it's not free? Well then scratch that. Fooled by the name "Open".

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah, that is what happened with me also.

Comment: OpenSTV (version 1.7) **is free software** as defined by the terms of version 2 of the GNU GPL. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78203/is-it-legal-for-stack-overflow-to-redistribute-openstv-binaries/78207#78207) for clarification.

Comment: @TimPost: I'm confused about that, the Downloads page talks about OpenSTV being only available anymore under a restrictive license, while saying that sourcecode is still available...and no link to that source in sight, but only the option to buy $99+ for it. I found a google project page, but that doesn't seem to house any source either. ... Ah, [there it is, the SourceForge project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/stv/)...but that doesn't have any source, either. `:/` I'm confused...

Comment: @Bobby It looks like they moved away from the GPL. However, any copy that you have which was given to you under the terms of the GPL is still covered by the GPL. This applies to the version that Stack Exchange makes available, AFAIK (Unless they're now distributing the newer version with the different EULA). I could, for instance give you my copy without worry, as my copy is covered by version 2 of the GNU GPL (which explicitly says, I am free to distribute the software  in its original or modified form, provided I obey the license when it comes to conveying a covered work).

Comment: @TimPost: So, they did rip all their source from the internet? That sucks. ... As far as I know (no lawyer), GNU GPL can't be 'undone' in any way, so if you're still serving the GPL version, it's GPL.

Comment: @Bobby I'm not sure, in fact the only time I even think about OpenSTV is when we have an election. You are correct, the GPL can not be "undone", anyone having a copy of a version covered by the GPL can do whatever the GPL permits *with their copy of that version*. New versions seem to have a different license. What I don't know is precisely which version Stack Exchange is distributing, but I suspect it hasn't changed (still the GPL2 version (1.7)).

Comment: @Bobby I updated my comment, and the answer it references.

Comment: @TimPost: All references I can find seem to indicate that 1.6.1 being the last FLOSS version (Debian/Ubuntu packages, Torrents with the source etc.. But 1.7 *seems* to be last version distributed freely, though, it seems to have been scorched from the face of the internet (only vague references).

Comment: Hopefully, someone has a copy of the source to 1.7 (as I believe that _is_ the version being distributed). You can't distribute it (modified or not) if you can't provide a downstream recipient a copy of the source, according to the GPL.

Comment: @TimPost: I'm unable to locate the 1.7 source, sadly. Seems like they nuked it from orbit pretty effectively. For 1.6.2 see the GitHub link in my comment on your other answer.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby: The SE version is the 1.7 binaries. The dmg contains a `License.html` that contains the text of the GPLv2 text. Stack Exchange is legally obligated to provide (I think?) provided they were distributing a version licensed to them under the GPLv2. But if they made an arrangement with the author beforehand, then SE is not bound by the GPL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These were excluded during a recent build system change - they will be back shortly.

Comment: By now I know I shouldn't be, but I'm rather amazed that anyone noticed.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the source code for the version we're distributing? See comments under the question.

Comment: @TimPost no we don't have the source code

Answer (score 4):

The error that comes is:

```
<!-- Actual error:

Could not find a part of the path &#39;C:\sites\stackexchange-network\content\downloads\OpenSTV-1.7-osx.dmg&#39;.-->


<!-- Actual error:

Could not find a part of the path &#39;C:\sites\stackexchange-network\content\downloads\OpenSTV-1.7-win32.exe&#39;.-->
```

Guess the fuzzy part which converts the link to a downloadable binary is broken :)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/OpenTechStrategies/openstv