# Election application from Open STV isn't free anymore

Tags: discussion, election

With an election:

> Download the election data and use [OpenSTV](http://www.openstv.org/download) to audit the results.

Previously, this was a free to download application.  It isn't anymore.

> ... To support continued development, OpenSTV is now available under a restrictive license.
>
> The license is for one year with prices ranging from $10 to $400. For small non-profits, the price is only $10. For medium non-profits, the price is $40. For all other organizations the price is $400. ...

The individual license is $10.
Given this, should Stack Exchange continue to promote the site for auditing running election returns?

Comment: Stack Exchange still provides the download directly for users who had enough reputation to participate in the election, so the software (at least whatever version Stack Exchange hosts) is at least still readily available in that respect.

Comment: @TimStone given that I've got the reputation *somewhere* on the network to participate in an election, should I be getting that message (I see now that if I go to another election where I did participate I can get the download).

Comment: I imagine that behaviour is by-design insomuch as no one's ever really given that any consideration.

Comment: Is https://github.com/OpenTechStrategies/openstv a viable alternative?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78203/is-it-legal-for-stack-overflow-to-redistribute-openstv-binaries

Answer (score 12):

I've been using https://github.com/OpenTechStrategies/openstv to run elections. It's the version of the software that was available prior to its commercialization.

I've never had results differ from the official reports in any way, and it's fairly easy to run (`python runElection.py MeekSTV someBallot.blt` or something like that).

Let's change the link to `https://github.com/OpenTechStrategies/openstv`, for all users.

Answer (score 11):

While the direct download link is still available if you have a certain amount of reputation, the link you get with low reputation is just entirely useless. It just mislead me into thinking that the software wasn't available at all anymore, while I still can access it if I go to an election on a different site.

The link should just be removed entirely, or the download should be available for more users.