# What are your "quality standards," and how do you meet them?

Tags: support, question-quality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

I ask because I cant post this question:

> The implementation of sqlite for web
>   doesnt come with encryption, so the
>   basic question is how do I protect
>   (encrypt) my database information on
>   the client side and still be usable
>   like a normal sql database?
>
> On the other case compile the
>   sqlite-version encrypted.... but, I
>   should find a "better way" for let my
>   wepapp embeded on iOS know the info in
>   a 2-way fashion.
>
> So how can I keep safe the information
>   in the database?

I have added [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite) [encrypt](/questions/tagged/encrypt) [web-sql](/questions/tagged/web-sql) [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tags.

Comment: Which error message are you getting? Is it *"This question does not meet our quality standards,"* or is it *"Sorry we are no longer accepting questions from this account"?*

Comment: @Robert Considering the title says "quality standars" [sic], I'm kinda in the impression that gnostra is in.

Comment: @Grace: Ah. Sorry, I tend to filter out mispeld [sic] words.

Comment: Run your question through a grammar and spell checker, check your capitalization, and try submitting your question again.

Comment: What was the question's title?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm sure spelling and punctuation are part of the quality *standards*. For example:

- doesnt -> doesn't
- wepapp -> web application
- embeded -> embedded

Comment: And yet, it appears no worse than many questions I've seen just today.

Comment: The second paragraph, "On the other case ...", is almost incomprehensible.

Comment: I see, I was thinking that it is best if stackoverflow give a separate "app/editor" for let foreign people to test their grammar... and have "compile errors" because like you have see, my impression was that my question was stupid instead of unreadable or with bad grammar.

You know, error messages in a program should inform the user of what is happening, not a "general error fault" like "your post doesn't meet our quality standards", I think if this program do those checks, is best if they give more useful information so one can use that information and don't come here asking why I can't post

Comment: @tyoc213: The [official answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards) is that if the system told you how to avoid the filter, you might be able to bypass it.  This is called a [Catch-22](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118875/1438).