# Message's first letter stays lowercase when redundant @user is truncated

Tags: bug, status-declined, comments, comment-replies, automatic-edits

I just noticed something that really bugs me on Stack Overflow.

There is `@`-syntax for summoning people in conversation.
Sometimes such `@`s are redundant.
One such situation is **when you try to summon the guy who posted the answer**.

As such, you don't have to say

> @Jon, you're a saint! Cleanse my heart.

because Jon gets notified of *any* comment on his answer.

I believe this is the reason SO **currently truncates** redundant @user part:

> you're a saint.  Cleanse my heart.

But **I don't want that**.   I wrote a sentence that **started with capital and finished with a dot**.
Now it starts with lowercase, which looks ugly.

Can we either cancel truncation, or uppercase truncated comments if they were uppercase in the first place?

> ### To summarize my point:
>
> I didn't **ask** the system to edit my comment. You know what—I don't *care* if the poster gets notified anyway.
> Good. You set the business rules.
>
> But why do **my comments get distorted for no apparent reason**, other than that I don't remember the business rules for @alerting?
>
> ### Solutions that look fine to me (in order of convenience):
>
> - remove the truncation (**@Jon, you're a saint**);
> - truncate **just `@`** (**Jon, you're a saint**)

Comment: I would just post "Jon, you're a saint! Cleanse my heart."

Comment: @Shadow: referring to people via @ has just become a mind pattern for me. I don't usually think whether the system will inform the person anyway—I just want to communicate my message, and the system distorts it. This is where it gets annoying.

Comment: My thesis is **if system is already smart enough to do alerts only once, it should not impose this business logic on me**. Otherwise the validation would have to occur once in the system and another time in my head, or I'll get an ugly comment.

Comment: I understand, but this is too minor to be considered bug in my opinion so just shared what I would do in such a case. :)

Comment: @Shadow: they **implemented the truncation** and this is a problem **caused by it**. I can't really understand the reason why such message *needs* to be truncated, therefore I think this bug is *just as important as truncation itself*. Or equally non-important (but equally!).

Comment: @ShadowWizard 'minor' as in non-breaking, yes, but it's still rape, of sorts. If we're trying to build a better internet, isn't malformation of others' sentences a little naive? I've been meaning to post something similar regarding the lower case 'p' at the beginning of the 'possible duplicate' auto-posts.

Comment: @Mr.Dis: The lower case 'p' has already been discussed. You should try and search.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capitalize "possible" in the automatically inserted comments when you vote to close as a dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44528/capitalize-possible-in-the-automatically-inserted-comments-when-you-vote-to-clo) since it establishes that the system doesn't care about capitalization, and it's funnier.

Comment: @Adam: *my* comments are not automatically inserted, mind you. I don't care how *system messages* look, at least as long as they're consistent. **But my comments consistently start uppercase, and I'd love to always keep them that way.**

Comment: @gaeron Even when the user's name who you are addressing obviously prefers a lowercase version of their username?

Comment: @Adam: I think you got me wrong... The problem is "@lowercasename: a sentence of mine" becomes "a sentence of mine". In the source string, I wouldn't uppercase user's first letter (because **user name is more important than grammar**). **But in the result string, there is no user name, and thus there is nothing here to justify grammar violation and eyehurt.**

Comment: @gaeron so if I prefer a lowercase style, you propose that the system uppercase my comment because you prefer an uppercase style?  Exactly how would the system determine what the user intended to have happen, or in other words, what rules do you propose that wouldn't uppercase comments for users that intentionally wanted lowercase, vs your comments where you prefer uppercase?

Comment: @Adam: I see your point now, thanks. Then it's better to not truncate the message at all.

Comment: @Adam: I edited the solutions to only include those that stick with user's style..

Comment: @HendrikVogt: I _should_ search? I could buy that if I was here asking a duplicate question, however, given that I only stated I had an intention to bring it up, I think your thinking I wouldn't search first is quite presumptuous, and frankly uncalled for in such a tone.

Comment: One advantage of the second fix (Jon, you're a saint) is that it educates users about when the @lert was automatic.  On an unrelated note, 'Lert' would be an awesome username.

Comment: ...can of worms.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm against this whole concept of removing "noise" like hi, thanks and now this - but learned to live with that. Back to the case: what if I wrote it all lower case and want it to be lower case? I don't want the system to decide for me, so Adam got good point in his answer.

Comment: The simpler fix is just to omit the unnecessary @reply portion in the first place. Then you'll capitalize it correctly and save the system from the hard work of cleaning up your comments in the first place.

Comment: @Mr.Dis: I'm sorry, I surely didn't mean to offend you. I was just trying to be nice and tell you that there's some discussion on that topic already. But you're right, when I look at my formulation a day later, I see that it's very easy to read it as coming from a presumptuous \*\*\*. (Here's a link to a [declined feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44528/capitalize-possible-in-the-automatically-inserted-comments-when-you-vote-to-clo).)

Comment: @Cody: Sometimes I want to call person by name. I don't want to omit the name.

Comment: Sure, I understand why people are objecting to the automatic removal of this information. It violates the principle of least surprise, and it's not doing a very good job of instructing people how to use the system because it doesn't *explain* that an unnecessary portion of their comment was snipped out. But that doesn't change the fact that it's here to stay. Requests to disable or modify it have been officially denied. So calling the original poster by name is no longer an option. My suggestion is to just omit the part that'll be inevitably removed, and thus capitalize it correctly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I didn't want the system to modify my comment in the first place.  Please don't make the system modify my comment any further.  Further modifications require assumptions that aren't always true.

Answer (score 7):

If it ain't broke, don't fix it. Why was this changed in the first place?