# Can SO stop making me look like an illiterate fool? ;)

Tags: bug, automatic-comments

Argh, this happens to me all the time: I type a comment like "@Jon can you please explain that part in more detail?" and it ends up as "can you please explain that part in more detail?". This makes me look like a fool that doesn't capitalise the first letter of sentences.

This was mentioned before:

[Message's first letter stays lowercase when redundant @user is truncated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97766/messages-first-letter-stays-lowercase-when-redundant-user-is-truncated)

This feature won't go away and automatically capitalising my comment would not be a perfect solution either, so I am fine with this. I (grudgingly) accept that.

BUT!

> possible duplicate of [Why does is_constructible claim something is constructible when it isn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815998/why-does-is-constructible-claim-something-is-constructible-when-it-isnt) – [R. Martinho Fernandes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46642/r-martinho-fernandes) [33 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404108/issue-with-is-copy-constructible#comment27032533_18404108)

What is this? There is no reason to have bad capitalisation on this one. Can this tiny little byte in the source code be fixed? Please? Pretty please? Please pretty please with sugar on top?

Comment: if it's any consolation, I don't think lack of capitals makes you look illiterate! just seems more casual

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ, s/if/If please.

Comment: Take your sugar, substitute it for a cherry, and you might have a chance....

Comment: Perhaps concentrate more on not looking like a fool who tags people who don't need tagging, then you can correctly capitalise all day long

Comment: hey, I never use capital letters at the start of my comments. I do use them on subsequent sentences. It's my preferred style, and I am anything but an illiterate fool.

Comment: @Kate see title edit.

Comment: I prefer to address my comments with a colon: "@Jon: Can you please explain that part in more detail?" Avoids the whole mess.

Comment: @AlEverett the things people learn do to appease the machines. This is what's wrong with the human condition :/ Pargmatics above truth

Comment: @AlEverett: I prefer to address my enemies with my colon

Comment: @sehe: Well, it seems to me to be more semantically correct. And I was doing it that way before the whole "delete at-address if only the post owner can get the notification anyway" anti-feature. No appeasement here.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Considering the tortured English we see on these sites in general, beginning a comment with a lowercase letter is too minor to even consider a problem.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ Casual, eh. Well, it *is* Friday!

Comment: Despite my vote to close, *I upvoted this feature request*, darn it! I feel your pain, I have been complaining about this for a long time now.