# Why are SEO keywords not in title case?

Tags: discussion, grammar

SEO keywords (from tags) are left in lower case in the title. For example, [How can I reject values from one array based on a parallel array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709282/how-can-i-reject-values-from-one-array-based-on-a-parallel-array) starts with "ruby - How can I ..."

Why is that?

Comment: Yes, it is one of the design mistakes of the Stack Overflow (they could just have deferred the discussion of the correct spellings to Wikipedia (let them fight over it)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeff Atwood's answer to a different [capitalization feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44528/capitalize-possible-in-the-automatically-inserted-comments-when-you-vote-to-clo/47209#47209) indicates that he doesn't think capital letters are always appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling that is simply to match the tag, as all tags are lower-case.

In the argument of SEO, it *does not matter*, as [search engines](http://www.google.com/search?q=are+not&oq=are+not) [tend not to be](http://www.google.com/search?q=Are+Not) [case specific](http://www.google.com/search?q=ARE+NOT).

Comment: It matters to me viewing the web page.