# Capitalize "Internet" in the close dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, grammar

According to many sources, including a well reputed [Stack Exchange site](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/644/should-the-words-internet-and-web-be-capitalized), and numerous dictionaries, the word *Internet* is a proper noun and should be capitalized. However, when voting for closing of a question, the following explanation appears for one of the options:

> This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only
>   relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an
>   extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to
>   the worldwide audience of the internet.

Can someone please fix this? Please?

Comment: "I felt a great disturbance in the Force, as if millions of pendants suddenly cried out in terror and no one cared." :P

Comment: Poor pendants. Every pendant should be hung where everyone can see them.  Around a neck, of course.  Very tightly...

Comment: There isn't "the Internet"; there is "the Internets."

Comment: Relevant to your interests: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44530/2915

Comment: @AdamDavis Very cool. = ) I will keep that in mind.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_capitalization_conventions

Comment: Your inefficient use of language bothers me: (1) "for weeks *now*": of course it's now... you used present tense! (2) "*and I'd like to express myself*": We know... you are doing it. No need to remind us that you didn't write this by physical compulsion. :-P

Comment: They'd just have to change it back in a few years when everybody has *inevitably* accepted that it's a common noun. Don't bother.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, there is only one Internet. But you can have multiple internets.

Comment: @Jonathan. That is not what a politician said by keeping to say "the Internets" instead of "the Internet." Guess you who was. `:-)`

Comment: @AdamDavis I am not sure whether to be ashamed of that typo, or proud for triggering your joke.  Kudos.

Answer (score 3):

In an effort to avoid ever fixing this bug (proving you are indeed correct), we completely refactored the close reasons instead.  Take that!  [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), we chose to remove the Internet instead.  Checkmate, buddy.

Comment: So where exactly are we now?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I'm afraid I can't answer that. Be afraid.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just like the *Sky* should be capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, per [Internet capitalization conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_capitalization_conventions) if you're talking about *the* Internet it is a proper noun which is capitalized. That message is referring to *the* Internet.

Comment: Or, if you scroll down a bit more, it [should not be capitalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_capitalization_conventions#The_argument_for_common_noun_usage) =)

Comment: I accidentally a whole the internet.  Will I die?

Comment: The Internet is quite clearly more important than the sky, it therefore deserves to be capitalised...