# Capitalize all system messages

Tags: discussion, feature-request, system-message

Sentences that don't start with a capital hurt to my eyes. Especially when they're this large:

[image]

There's more: the system posts for you sometimes (for the 'possible duplicate' message). These autoposts don't always have a capital, and then it's like *I* wrote that sentence without a capital. This specific case [has been brought up already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44528/205264).

Given the votecounts on that question and the answers (also note the -34 on Jeff's authorative answer - the reason for [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)), wouldn't it be a good idea to go over all the system messages and capitalize<sup>1</sup> them?

---

From Jeff's answer:

> It's not a complete sentence,

True - although not for the 'put on hold'.

> so it doesn't need to be capitalized.

Doesn't *need* to, but people expect it.

> We don't capitalize the tabs on the user page, or the homepage, for example.. or, heck, even here on the question page itself.

That's different - they're short slugs, not informational texts.

---

<sup>1: with *capitalize* I mean let every sentence start with a capital, like you normally do</sup>

Comment: Please note that this is not a duplicate of the linked post since I request to capitalize all system messages.

Comment: DO YOU MEAN CAPITALIZE ALL SYSTEM MESSAGES OR ENSURE THAT THE FIRST LETTER IS A CAPITAL LETTER? :-)

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards rAndoMlY oF CouRSe! :-)

Comment: At least it's not a pluralization 'bug'...

Comment: @Undo Maybe it is, and the OP is just trying to cover it up with the guise of capitalization. We're on to you, Camil.

Comment: @CamilStaps It's a joke here on Meta. Jeff Atwood, the co-founder of SE, famously wrote [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694).

Comment: (Note: This is basically the plan now since [Stacks guidelines](https://stackoverflow.design) recommend using sentence case – but there's a lot of legacy code to fix.)