# When flagging duplicates, the auto-posted comment should be capitalized correctly

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, wording, automatic-comments

When flagging a question as duplicate a comment is auto posted on the first one to flag (or vote to close) behalf. Can it please get proper case?

> [image]

Or in words, make it:

> Possible duplicate of ...

Instead of:

> possible duplicate of ...

Comment: Please write proper feature request, with the request in the **post body**, not only in title. Plus, choose relevant tags.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Ah, sorry, I've updated the question.

Comment: It's still a mess, sorry. Oh well, guess I must do it myself. :)

Comment: I, for one, am waiting for the giant P to make an appearance.

Comment: What about prepending "This is a" to the current comment or something to that effect?

Comment: I believe this to be a possible duplicate of [Capitalize “possible” in the automatically inserted comments when you vote to close as a dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44528/179419).

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy you mean "This is a possible duplicate of"?

Comment: Mine has a full-stop as well @Sha; a sentence needs an end point :-).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I mean something like "This is a possible duplicate of: [The Many Memes of Meta](http://example.com)."

Comment: @ben, you nicely fooled the [overly-active "duplicate" comment deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141414/dont-delete-comments-with-link-to-duplicate-if-they-are-modified/195654#195654) there! ;-)

Comment: That's astounding @Arjan; I was expecting it to be deleted. Do you think the capitalisation and full-stop may have made a difference ;-).

Answer (score 2):

It's a sentence fragment, not a complete sentence, and as such it shouldn't be capitalized.

Comment: To be honest, it is used as a complete sentence (comments should be properly formed sentences, right?). I do recapitalize it every time I vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi There is no subject to which the verb is applied, so no, it's not a complete sentence.

Comment: True. It looks like an implied subject, though, I'll have to check on [english.se]. (Done, found [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/66972) which explains this is proper *spoken* English but improper *written* English, so you're right.)

Comment: @Servy Not convinced by your argument. Are all grammar bets off if it's a fragment then?

Comment: @DuncanJones Well, it's intended to be a sentence fragment by the person that wrote it, as per the duplicate.  That it's not capitalized and has no punctuation makes that intent all the more clear.