# Why is the footer copyright declaration in lowercase?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, copyright, footer

The footer copyright declaration at the bottom of the page

[image]

is in lower-case (completely). I want to know if there is some particular reason for this? Why is it not Titled-Case or Sentenced-case?

Comment: I'm sure JQuery can make it look any way you want with a simple userscript.

Comment: @jmac: I think this is not about "that should be changed" but rather "why exactly?".

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby yes, my qyestion is "why?". And if it is not on purpose, then ofcourse we ought to change it we think that should be the case.

Comment: What kind of answer are you expecting other than *because that's what the designer thought looked nice*?

Comment: I don't know. If it isn't specifically so, it should be changed, shouldn't it be?

Comment: Note that it's consistent with about, help, blog, etc. at the bottom of the page (not that I care a whole lot about this).

Comment: If it’s lowercase for design reasons, it should be handled with CSS’s `text-transform`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jeff says [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47209/152859): (in a highly unpopular response)

> It's not a complete sentence, so it doesn't need to be capitalized. We don't capitalize the tabs on the user page, or the homepage, for example

Consider the copyright declaration:

> site design / logo © 2013 stack exchange inc;

That's indeed not a full sentence. It's not "This site was designed by...". As a declaration only, it does not get treated as a sentence.

While I personally does not agree with Jeff reasoning, that's most likely the reason.

Comment: The *highly unpopular* words should be in **BOLD** lol! (37 downvotes!)

Comment: "stack exchange inc" now is Capitalized in the footer.

Comment: @älёxölüt sure, it's a name. But the first word (site) is not capitalized yet.