# Why are Stack Exchange navigation bar links in lowercase?

Tags: feature-request, footer

It could be uppercase at first letter of each links (not tags).

Comment: It looks better in all lowercase.

Comment: I find this is just a cosmetic issue and doesn't really affect user's experience at all, so let it be. (I don't have any preference to make it lowercase or Title-Case, but current design is already okay)

Comment: @Code3d In that case, you should retag this as [meta-tag:feature-request] instead of [meta-tag:discussion].

Comment: Code3d - you think it would be an improvement. I feel it would be the opposite. So there are at least two schools of thought here...so why not leave it be :-)

Answer (score 2):

From [Capitalize "possible" in the automatically inserted comments when you vote to close as a dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44528/capitalize-possible-in-the-automatically-inserted-comments-when-you-vote-to-cl/47209#47209)

> It's not a complete sentence, so it doesn't need to be capitalized. We don't capitalize the tabs on the user page, or the homepage, for example.. or, heck, even here on the question page itself.

That question is 4 years old, but I suppose SE still holds the same stance or doesn't really care about such tiny details.

Also related: [Why is the footer copyright declaration in lowercase?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207520/why-is-the-footer-copyright-declaration-in-lowercase)

Comment: I think first letter uppercase will look fine.

Comment: @Code3d I think all lowercase looks fine. For every person who shares your opinion, you'll find someone who likes the way it looks now. There are hundreds of thousands of websites that use lowercase in their navigation, just like there are hundreds of thousands of websites that use capitalisation in their navigation.

Comment: SE has since [reversed their stance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267134/351462) on the linked issue