# Capitalize "your reputation" in topbar tooltip

Tags: bug, top-bar, tooltips, capitalization

Most tooltips in the topbar are capitalized:

> [image: inbox]
>
> [image: achivements]
>
> [image: review]
>
> [image: help]
>
> [image: winter]
>
> [image: sites]

But not the reputation:

> [image: reputation]

Let's capitalize your reputation!

Comment: Please stand by while we mail you a comically large capital Y. While stocks last (which they never do)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek me already have [one from Yandex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gUB7.jpg), but I will wait for another one from Stack Overflow. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the rationale is the same as the [footer copyright being lower case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207520/why-is-the-footer-copyright-declaration-in-lowercase).

I'll quote the same sentence from Jeff:

> It's not a complete sentence, so it doesn't need to be capitalized. We don't capitalize the tabs on the user page, or the homepage, for example

So, the words "your reputation" can't really be seen as "complete sentence" that stands on its own, hence should not be capitalized.

Comment: None of those are [complete sentences](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/completesentence.htm) that stand on their own since none of them has a verb.

Comment: @terdon well, they are complete descriptions then, that describe something so can act as title.

Comment: Sure, but so's "Your reputation". I just don't see how that one is any different and since the rest are capitalized, it does seem reasonable (although certainly not urgent) to capitalize that one as well.