# Stack Exchange should be capitalized in the copyright

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, copyright, footer, capitalization

In the footer of every Stack Exchange site, it says:

> site design / logo © 2014 stack exchange inc; user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required

I think "stack exchange" there should be capitalized, as "Stack Exchange" is a proper noun.

Comment: I'd prefer they use proper casing in that entire line, not just the network name.

Comment: [Trademark Guidance](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) only covers _other_ people using their name/logo. I suppose since it's their site they can do it however they want. It's a style thing, I guess.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce Contesting the duplicate. I'm just asking about the brand name, not the entire sentence fragment.

Comment: Partially agree. Original form wasn't different enough, so I took the liberty to change this into a feature request before reopening it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks.

Comment: Why exactly should it be capitalized?  Just aesthetics?

Comment: @snailplane Because it's the brand name, and as such a proper noun.

Comment: This is not just pedantry.  Scimonster and I (and others) are currently working on a publication (reproducing SE content) in which we'll need to recognize Stack Exchange's copyright, and it seems silly for us to print "stack exchange" when the name of the company is Stack Exchange.  We can just do the logical and IMO correct thing in our publication, but why not also fix it at the source?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I did almost two hours of research on this... posted my answer below. I feel that company name should conform to what it's registered as.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: Actually, SE content is governed by the CC licence, not "copyright". You need to provide attribution, not a "copyright" statement.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit actually, what we were using was the site logo, so that is SE's copyright.  We also attributed the content per CC-BY-SA.  Belatedly I realize that that comment wasn't clear enough; sorry about that.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: Okay :)

Answer (score 5):

Was just going to ask about this.

As it's stated officially to be "*Stack Exchange Inc*" in the [legal/trademark-guidance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) (at the bottom), then wouldn't it be prudent to conform and have continuity?
I know it's "only a footer" but it should be *right*.

So the "stack exchange inc" should be "Stack Exchange Inc" as per the official name.

And, possibly while at it, change "cc by-sa" to "CC-BY-SA", because that is the correct way to write that initialism.

(There's also a rogue single space at the end of that line in the footer.)

Comment: i agree if only because this fad of righting everyfing in lowahcase wit poor speling is rly fkn annoyin!!!!11

Answer (score 5):

The [Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) section in the legal trademark guidance page says:

> **Stack Exchange Inc.** is the official name of the company.

So, as per the given official name, it should be "**Stack Exchange Inc.**" (notice the ***dot*** after Inc) and *not* "stack exchange inc".

Upon doing further research on the corporation (or the legal business entity) name, I found the following facts.

- **[EDGAR** (Electronic Data-Gathering, Analysis, and Retrieval)](http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?CIK=0001491819&action=getcompany):

  EDGAR system performs automated collection, validation, indexing,
  acceptance, and forwarding of submissions by companies and others who
  are required by law to file forms with the U.S. Securities and
  Exchange Commission (the "SEC").

  > EDGAR system search says: **Stack Exchange, Inc.**
- **[NYS Department of State**, Division of Corporations:](http://appext20.dos.ny.gov/corp_public/CORPSEARCH.ENTITY_INFORMATION?p_nameid=3944882&p_corpid=3937125&p_entity_name=Stack%20Exchange&p_name_type=A&p_search_type=BEGINS&p_srch_results_page=0) (for some reasons info. is printed in "CAPITAL" letters)

  The Corporation and Business Entity Database includes business and not-for-profit corporations, limited partnerships, limited liability companies and limited liability partnerships, as well as other miscellaneous businesses.

  > NY DOS database search says: **STACK EXCHANGE, INC.**

IMO, the correct way to write a company name is to write it as the company registered its own name. So, based on the above facts, the "stack exchange inc" should be changed to "**Stack Exchange, Inc**." (proper noun; notice the ***comma*** and ***dot***). But, if the company's official doc. says "**Stack Exchange Inc.**" then let's go with that *at least* and *not* with "stack exchange inc".

I completely agree with the comments posted (under the questions above) by Monica Cellio (elected ♦ moderator) and animuson (employee ♦ moderator).

Comment: Nicely done, +1