# Company name in the copyright of Stack Overflow Careers site correctly shows "Stack Exchange Inc."

Tags: discussion, status-completed, jobs, copyright, footer

Please *do not* mark this question as a duplicate of [Stack Exchange should be capitalized in the copyright](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243913/stack-exchange-should-be-capitalized-in-the-copyright) (I have just [posted my answer] [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243913/stack-exchange-should-be-capitalized-in-the-copyright/261653#261653) there) as that question talks about the *proper way to display the company name* whereas my question is about the *change I noticed* in the copyright section of the Stack Overflow Careers website.

I just noticed the following: (Showing only the relavent part)

**The footer of the [Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) site currently shows:**

> site design / logo © 2015 Stack Exchange Inc.

> [image]

**The footer of the [Stack Exchange and its Network](https://stackexchange.com/) sites shows:**

> site design / logo © 2015 stack exchange inc

**The [legal trademark guidelines](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) page says:**

> **Stack Exchange Inc.** is the official name of the company.

Why ***only*** Stack Overflow Careers website uses "**Stack Exchange Inc.**" (***conforms*** to the official name) whereas most of the Stack Exchange and its Network sites are using "**stack exchange inc**" as the company name in the copyright section. Is this something a new change? Can anyone please explain this.

Comment: I just noticed that all of the sites are getting copyright footer update with "Stack Exchange Inc." Is this a new build push? Can anyone confirm this.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that this will soon get a *completed* status tag. The dot after _Inc_ is still missing, though.

Comment: @chirlu I noticed that too... but that will be too much to ask... I am afraid someone may put "feature request" for the same, I hope not. If you read [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243913/stack-exchange-should-be-capitalized-in-the-copyright/261653#261653) you will see that I put that in there too.

Comment: It's fixed everywhere, except for Area 51.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Careers and Stack Overflow have historically had mostly separate teams working on them, so they aren't always 100% in sync.

But it appears someone noticed and made them agree with each other more.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to have been silently fixed on all sites <s>but StackExchange.com</s>:

MSE:

> [image: MSE]

Super User:

> [image: Super User]

Stack Overflow:

> [image: Stack Overflow]

<s>But not StackExchange.com:</s>  Update: It has been fixed here as well now :)

Comment: I think this is a recent build.... StackOverflow.com and few others were using "stack exchange inc". I wish I had taken the screenshot of them. Looks like now stackexchange.com is FIXED too! .... What's happening here ... As I type this comment and check they are all getting updated... Can anyone confirm

Comment: yep confirmed - fixed on all (I think) sites now! :)

Comment: It probably is a new build - they're pushing it out without saying so *yet*!

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Looks like everything is fixed... I see the recent build "rev 2015.7.29.2757" (on most of the SE Network sites), except "rev 2015.7.29.3615" for Meta.SE and 2015.7.29.2204 for stackexchange.com

Comment: @HackerKarma Correct, SE.com, MSE/MSO, and "most SE Network sites" are all separate builds. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267231/13, for example.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Thanks for the update. It definitely makes sense now.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young by the way, this hasn't reached CHAT yet... :P

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Chat is a totally separate project. Please file a separate meta post for that. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267551/260841