# Same revision (or build) number but the company name in copyright mis-match

Tags: bug, status-completed, copyright, footer

Here is the current footer of [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

> [image]

and here is the current footer of the [meta.stackexchange.com/users/login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login) and [meta.stackexchange.com/users/signup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/signup)

> [image]

The revision (or build) number on all of them shows as **rev 2015.7.31.3625** and all of the three pages namely **main page** of Meta SE, the **login page** and the **sign up page** are currently residing under the same domain i.e. **meta.stackexchange.com**. So, how could the company name (Stack Exchange Inc v/s stack exchange inc) in the copyright footer gets mis-match? Are they pulled from the different files that stores the copyright? Can anyone please explain.

The company name was corrected on the most of the Stack Exchange Network sites in the yesterday's build and a [status-completed was added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261657/company-name-in-the-copyright-of-stack-overflow-careers-site-correctly-shows-st) by moderator Laura.

**P.S:**

Both of the pages i.e. "Login" and "Sign up" are part of this [New year, new experiment: Login and Signup UI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246689/new-year-new-experiment-login-and-signup-ui) which went effect yesterday as per the post status of [Upcoming login changes (Stage 2 and the new UI now LIVE)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/upcoming-login-changes-stage-2-and-the-new-ui-now-live).

Comment: Note about "yesterday's build": As per my observation, the build "rev 2015.7.29.2757" (on most of the SE Network sites), "rev 2015.7.29.3615" for Meta.SE and 2015.7.29.2204 for stackexchange.com fixed the company name in the footer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like we need to standardize a few things between our various master pages! Thanks, should be fixed soon.