# Update capitalisation in footer copyright of SEDE to match sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, footer, capitalization

The capitalisation of "Stack Exchange" in the footer's copyright on the sites was corrected, per this Meta discussion:

- [Stack Exchange should be capitalized in the copyright](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243913/stack-exchange-should-be-capitalized-in-the-copyright).

However, the Stack Exchange Data Explorer footer is still lowercase:

[image]

Could the capitalisation be changed to be consistent with the sites?

Comment: I blame Tim Stone.

Comment: I wonder how many bug reports it's gonna take . . .

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M usually Tim is fast, bottleneck is a dev that has to pull the change and deploy on the live server. :/

Comment: @Sha I meant "how many bug reports it's gonna take to make the name of the company right in the footers for God's sake"!

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M 6-8 of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That wasn't the only inconsistency, but it's [now patched](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/69), pending a pull and redeploy:

[image: fixed footer]

Comment: …And before anyone says anything I know I added one hyphen too many in the screenshot's "cc-by-sa", but have no fear, it's correct in the actual commit.

Comment: I would have left the hyphen and the dear next person who opened a bug report about it ... you know the drill...