# Update capitalisation in footer copyright of Area 51 to match sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, footer, capitalization

The capitalisation of "Stack Exchange" in the footer's copyright on the sites was corrected, per this Meta discussion:

- [Stack Exchange should be capitalized in the copyright](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243913/stack-exchange-should-be-capitalized-in-the-copyright).

However, the Area 51 footer is still lowercase:

[image]

Could the capitalisation be changed to be consistent with the sites?

Comment: Similar to [SEDE request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263764/update-capitalisation-in-footer-copyright-of-sede-to-match-sites), posted per [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3840614#3840614)

Comment: [tag:status-fix-all-tha-footerz]

Comment: The shame! Dost thou hath  no honour? Or is this treachery before mine eyes? I shall make haste to Y! and utilise this site no longer until said scandal is steadfastly resolved. Mortimar, Mortimar, bring henceforth the horses, we shall make haste before the darkness cometh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed and will appear as of build 377. In line with the footer on Stack Overflow, it will say "Stack Exchange Inc" with no comma and no dot.

Comment: Not Stack Overflow Inc?

Comment: @NormalHuman No, the legal name of the company is still Stack Exchange Inc. Stack Overflow is our "doing business as" name.