# possible grammar of "Voting that a post is a duplicate"

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign, comments, grammar

Upon voting that a post is a duplicate of another post, a comment under your name is automatically posted that looks something like this:

> possible duplicate of "`<post_name>`"

This is hardly a complete sentence, never mind the fact that message doesn't end in a period nor does it start with a capital letter.

It should be something like this:

> This post is a possible duplicate of "`<post_name>`".

In Stack Exchange, proper grammar is strongly enforced in almost every single SE site; so why does the automatic message generated by Stack Exchange itself not follow this rule?

Comment: Highly related/possible dupe candidate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44528/capitalize-possible-in-the-automatically-inserted-comments-when-you-vote-to-cl since that was declined, I doubt whether if this one ends up [tag:status-completed].

Comment: @HDE226868 Yes, I meant to write that; that was an error on my part.

Comment: quick question why is this question is not marked as dupe of that one? just wondering... do we all (those upvoted and seen nn times) wants this? Why not-reopen the [status-declined]  again

Comment: @HackerKarma The question is currently under review for being closed as a duplicate. I'm *not* voting to close because this question differs from the other in that this one requests a full sentence, while the other merely asks for a single capital letter.

Comment: @Shokhet Thank you for the explanation. I couldn't understand what's the difference in these two questions. So, it's a single char v/s. full sentence.

Answer (score 5):

As noted in [the linked post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44528/13), I changed the "possible duplicate" to "Possible duplicate". This seems to be satisfactory to many people.

You have 5 minutes to edit any comment that you own, including auto-generated ones. Please feel free to edit its contents to your liking, if "Possible duplicate" is not sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

There are arguments for and against.

My first thought was "Who cares", the comment is coherent and fine, and these comments tend to be quite short lived.

Then I remembered that they are not always short lived.
And that our names are on them.
And I "doubt" changing it would entail great deal of work.

I know, there is a *huge* todo list - I sympathise with that, but "status-declined" is different to "yeah we should do this, could be some time though, perhaps 6-8 (or longer)".

---

I can only presume the current message comes from a time long ago when the site was a baby, and such functionality was plumbed in quickly - "Ah, that works, that'll do, it's fine".

Whereas now, Stack is an extremely popular and large collection of sites, and strives to be grammatically correct in all places.

The low quality post review choices auto-generate comments in our name, and they're grammatically correct, such as:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or
>   request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their
>   post.

Capitals, full stops, even a comma in that one.

---

My conclusion is, I agree and I think it should be changed, and see no reason why it shouldn't.

Comment: Generally, [tag:status-deferred] is applied to anything that will be up to consideration in the future, usually 6 to 8 weeks. :P

Comment: It's possible it's a deliberate attempt to keep us all uncomfortable with the current (slightly hackish) dupes-as-close-reason setup so we'll adjust to the dupes-as-specialized-answers change when that is finally designed and implemented in 6-8 years.