# Dupe comments are dupes

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

The new auto-comment feature for dupes is adding the same comment for each user that votes to close for the same reason. This just adds a lot of noise - traditionally, people have simply upvoted the original (manual) comment describing the dupe. Can I suggest that only the first dupe vote referring to a specific question should get a comment?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544577/type-casting-c-and-c-closed for an example.

Comment: Isn't it cool that the SO-team has free bug/user-testers?

Comment: Isn't it cool that the SO-team has free bug/user-testers?

Comment: @Ivo, Clients doing your QA = bad

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dupe comments are dupes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44534/dupe-comments-are-dupes)

Comment: @Qui-Gon Jinn: what's the difference between testing it on your site and doing some hallway testing? It's not like it's the worst mistake ever ;-)

Comment: @Jeff Well that's what I call a fast response - thank you!

Comment: @Ivo: Considering that we don't pay anything for stack overflow, isn't it fair enough that we provide free bug/user testing?

Comment: @Pollyanna: Considering that we don't pay anything for stack overflow, isn't it fair enough that we provide free bug/user testing?

Comment: @andrew We don't pay anything for using the site, but on the other hand we don't get paid for answering the questions - it cuts both ways. Having said that, I don't mind being experimented on so long as the powers that be respond to suggestions for imporovements, which in this case they have.

Answer (score 2):

According [to Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44173/autocomment-when-voting-to-close-as-duplicate/44529#44529):

> - <strike>once closed, the question should auto-remove any comments of the type "possible duplicate of.."</strike>
> - <strike>when multiple people vote for the same dupe, should not insert duplicate comments (oh, the irony)</strike>

So, I guess this is work-in-progress?

(And the wish for the upvote is in the same explanation.)

**Update**: Jeff did some strikethrough, which I copied here. Might indicate it's already done (quick!), or will never be implemented. ;-)

Comment: looks like WIP to me!  :)

Comment: I don't think the comments should be auto-removed once closed, as if the question is re-opened there won't be any record of why it was closed the first time, and the process will begin again probably using the same close reason.

Comment: @Neil: The duplicate links will be in the edit history, and any discussion on them won't be auto-deleted. (As I understand how it's supposed-to/will-eventually work out.)

Comment: (And, any ideas on that should be posted at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44173/autocomment-when-voting-to-close-as-duplicate/44529#44529 I guess?)

Comment: @arjan: no auto-comment for me, apparently.  maybe since my vote closed it out?  not sure.  (i guess you deleted your comments but the system notified me anyway; this re: http://superuser.com/questions/125660/opening-large-txt-file-in-windows-closed ... ahh, i see your testing comment in the timeline on that question)

Comment: @quack - Just wip it!  Wip it good!

Comment: @Pollyanna: did you see that movie last year?  great movie once i saw it, but i never actually saw a trailer for it, and anytime i saw the title i wondered why the hell anyone'd want to make a movie about Devo.  (spoiler: movie is not actually about Devo.)

Comment: @quack - nope.  I've heard really good things about How to Train Your Dragon, though, and am looking forward to seeing that: http://www.schlockmercenary.com/blog/index.php/2010/03/28/how-to-train-your-epic-hero-in-95-minutes/ - I spent way too much time yesterday reading about monomyth related stuff...

Comment: @Polly: good to see another schlock fan.  the comic's good, but i've been hooked on his movie reviews since reading [his Bloodrayne review](http://www.schlockmercenary.com/blog/index.php/2006/01/06/movie-review-bloodrayne/).

Comment: @quack - Huzzah!  Another Schlock fan!  We should swap webcomic reading lists sometime.

Comment: @Polly @quack wow, I knew I wasn't alone based on HoTay's apparent success, but I've never actually met another reader.  +1 each for the completely Meta-inappropriate reason &#8212; insofar as such a thing can exist &#8212; of being Schlock fans.