# Instantly show the automatically posted comment when voting to close

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, vote-to-close

The recent [auto-comment-on-close feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44173/autocomment-when-voting-to-close-as-duplicate) is a good thing; however I wonder if most close voters are aware that their close vote triggers a comment being posted in their name, because they won't see it unless they refresh the page.

I suggest to AJAX-reload the comments or at least auto-refresh the page when the vote triggered a comment.

Comment: That would be helpful.  I only recently discovered this functionality had been implemented after leaving a comment on a question I had voted to close as dupe.  After a page refresh, I saw a comment had already been left on my behalf.  I can see this causing a lot of unintentional duplicate comments by users who are unaware of this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auto-generated comment is now loaded via ajax.

Comment: Jeff & @Jarrod, could this be broken? I've not seen this for a while. (I do see the "close" link change into "close (1)", but not the comment.)

Comment: @Arjan: Yep, that was broken. Fixed in the next build.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit jarring to see a comment from you when revisiting a question you've voted to close. Makes you wonder what else you've been doing that you don't really remember.

AJAX-reloading the comments would allow you to see the comment and further edit it to add more information as to why you think it's a dupe, if you so please (I sometimes do that).

Comment: If you've been to college, then you should be used to this feeling.