# Bug: deleting my comment edited the one above it

Tags: support, comments

I commented on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804041/constructor-in-a-interface) that it was a duplicate of another, providing the link to the original question in my comment.

I then noticed 1) another user had already left a very similar comment, and 2) upon re-reading the question again that while the basic premise itself ("Why can't a Java interface have a constructor?") is a duplicate, the question-asker provided more details about *what* the he/she wanted to do which was not covered in the original qusetion.

After posting an answer, I deleted my original "This is a duplicate of..." comment.

I noticed a few minutes later in re-visiting this question that while my comment was deleted, the "Possible duplicate" comment left by a previous user now has **my** name next to it.

It seems that deleting my comment not only removed my comment but changed the author of the first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curious -- those comments are automatically added when you vote to close.  Did you, perhaps, vote to close the question?  It may be that both you and the other person deleted your manually added comments, but the autogenerated comment didn't appear until after you refreshed the page.

Comment: I commented about the possible duplicate, voted to close, and then deleted my comment. Didn't realize that these comments were auto-generated.

Comment: In other words, I left a manual comment, voted to close, later removed my manual comment, then noticed the "Possible duplicate" comment - so I'm likely just mistaking an auto-generated comment for something other than what it is.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46445/instantly-show-the-automatically-posted-comment-when-voting-to-close