# New "4 more votes needed to close" popup causes page refresh

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, user-interface

The new popup with drop-shadow that appears after the vote-to-close dialog seems to refresh the entire page when it is clicked. I'm sure the previous version didn't do that (or am I halucinating?) If it didn't, can we go back to the old behaviour please?

Comment: reprodcued (FF 3.5 on Vista)

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome 6-dev on Ubuntu.  It only happens when you dismiss the box.  Appears to happen no matter the number of close votes remaining.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed - the page will no longer refresh after voting.

See this request for more information:

[Instantly show the automatically posted comment when voting to close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46445/instantly-show-the-automatically-posted-comment-when-voting-to-close)