# When voting to close as duplicate, please give a visual indicator of the automatically added comment

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I like to have input into the comments on SO in my name, but occasionally forget that voting to close something as a dupe (and other actions?) is going to automatically post a comment, ostensibly by me.  When I notice, I can [adjust the grammar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44528/137004) before the editing window closes.

Since the grammar apparently isn't getting any better, how about **adding some visual indicator that there's a new comment by me**, that I might want to look at?

Maybe flashing the comment as when linking to an answer.  Maybe a message at the top like "Added comment by you."  Whatever, proposals welcome.

[Similar concerns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46445/instantly-show-the-automatically-posted-comment-when-voting-to-close) have already led to it being loaded via AJAX immediately, this would just extend that change a bit.

---

**Update**:
I didn't actually intend to rekindle old debates over comment formatting.  I just like having input into what's on SO under my name, and occasionally forget that sometimes such content will be automatically generated.  Since I'm evidently not alone in being surprised by this behavior, I thought the UI might have room for improvement.

Comment: Or you can post the comment beforehand exactly how you want it, because if it detects that the link is already in the comments, it doesn't add another comment. :)

Comment: A little emphasis couldn't hurt, I was surprised to find I had suddenly left such a comment myself

Comment: Wait...you're worried about the grammar of that automatic comment which will get removed if the question is closed?

Comment: @animuson If I'm thinking to add a comment ahead of time, I wouldn't need a reminder about the automatic comment.  It's the times that I'm not thinking to comment at all that are at issue.

Comment: @Kobobby Mostly I want to be aware of all the content on the site that's attributed to me.  That the system also automatically deletes the words it put in my mouth is good, I guess, but in the interim I'd like to be sure I've had a chance to offer input.