# Do not delete *edited* vote-to-close auto-comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, vote-to-close

The [autocomment when voting to close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44173/autocomment-when-voting-to-close-as-duplicate) feature says:

> Once the question is closed (even if it is not closed as a duplicate), these comments are deleted and the duplicate information is automatically edited into the question itself.

I'd suggest to check if a comment was edited, before deleting it this way. Sometimes I dislike the standard message and add additional information to it ... but unfortunately all I wrote gets deleted.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46799/automatic-possible-duplicate-links-are-removed-even-if-the-question-isnt-close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the comment deleted, make sure it doesn't begin with "possible duplicate of"

Comment: Great ... that's what I am looking for

Comment: Just curious: are *all* comments that start with *"possible duplicate of"* auto-deleted, even those that have not been added by the system?

Comment: Is this a case-sensitive check?

Comment: That violates the Principle of Least Astonishment.  How about not deleting the comment if it has been edited at all? That should be easy to check for -- just use the same check that displays the pencil icon.

Comment: @Ether: yes, I'd go with this implementation, too. Right now I have to remember to change the beginning of a comment to make it persistent.

Comment: I don't think *"make sure it doesn't begin with "possible duplicate of""* is true anymore? It seems that *any* comment that holds the word "duplicate" anywhere in the comment, is boldly deleted? I added [a comment](http://i.stack.imgur.com/g4NYh.png) that referred to a duplicate *of an example given in the question* (so: I was not claiming [the question itself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158053/set-favorite-questions-name-description) was a duplicate), and that was also deleted when the question was closed. (cc. @tanascius)

Comment: Today, [an edited auto-comment of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163611/bold-italics-in-codeblocks#comment474047_163611) was left in place after closure. So: seems things have been fixed, and that it doesn't even matter if the edited comment still starts with *"possible duplicate of"*. Nice. (cc. @tanascius)

Comment: @arjan not sure, but it would be trivial to code, since there is an edit counter on comments, so.. `if editcounter > 0 then` ...

Comment: Since the text of “possible duplicate of” comment has been change, does the code still check for hardcoded text?

Answer (score 0):

...or, to avoid editing, simply make "Community" the owner of those comments? ([Some](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44173/autocomment-when-voting-to-close-as-duplicate/44176#44176) would rather not have their name attached to such auto-comment, for some vote-privacy until the question is closed, and hence it's proven that others agree.)

Comment: But the name is already attached, isn't it? So this is a different proposal

Comment: @tanascius, you're right, I added *to avoid editing* to clarify my point.

Comment: Ok, I see ... this would help in the case you descibe - but not in all cases; for instance when I just add some more explainations why I voted to close and maybe even another link or something valuable

Comment: @tanascius, I thought it would also help in the other cases, assuming *only* the auto-generated comment would be deleted, which *you* wouldn't be able to edit if those were owned by Community. And hence, you'd be forced to write your own comment. Now, given Jeff's answer, I wonder if *all* comments that start with *"possible duplicate of"* are auto-deleted, even those that have not been added by the system.