# Is there any benefit to upvoting a comment?

Tags: feature-request, comments, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work)

Usually when our answers get upvoted on Stack Overflow, we earn 10 reputation points. Similarly, are there any points awarded for comment upvotes on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Arjan: couldn't resist, just **had** to upvote your comment. :P

Comment: @Studio, that was [an auto-comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44173/autocomment-when-voting-to-close-as-duplicate), which has been [auto-deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47443/do-not-delete-edited-vote-to-close-auto-comments) as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apart from a good feeling there is a silver badge: `Pundit` - left 10 comments with score of 10 or more. This badge is given once. It has been awarded [37 times in meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/40/pundit) and [128 times in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/94/pundit), so it's rather exclusive.

No points, but your upvoted comment stays visible when there are many comments on an answer, such that non-upvoted comments get hidden.