# When retracting a close vote, if that vote led to a comment, the comment is not deleted

Tags: feature-request, comments, vote-to-close, automatic-comments, retracted-close-votes

An example would be a vote as a duplicate. When the user retracts the vote of a duplicate, the comment is left behind. Personally, I'd like to see these auto-comments reconsidered, but at least delete comments left due to a close vote when the close vote is retracted.

Comment: I don't think comments are marked in any way to indicate that it was automatically created. I don't really see why manual deletion doesn't suffice though.

Comment: @animuson This may be technically not feasible if you're correct. However, I'd like to avoid forgetting to delete irrelevant comments.

Comment: I also wonder how this affects available close reasons. Say, you vote to close as off-topic and provide a comment. Then you retract the vote. Is that custom close reason still available to future voters? Maybe we should remove it if no other votes have been cast that used the same comment.

Comment: When deleting, should a new auto-comment be created if meanwhile someone else voted for the same reason? And I'm sure @animuson is right, and auto-comments are not marked as such. We've seen cases where [more than only the automated comment got deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141414/dont-delete-comments-with-link-to-duplicate-if-they-are-modified/#comment460725_141414) though in April 2010 [Jeff wrote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47443/do-not-delete-edited/47446#47446) *If you don't want the comment deleted, make sure it doesn't begin with "possible duplicate of"*.

Comment: Worth to mention that when the question is closed as duplicate, the auto comment **is auto deleted** - so such process already exists. The process isn't very smart though, it just search the comments and remove any comment with link to the dupe - people already complained it removed other, not automatic, comments.

Comment: @animuson I faced the same situation [recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5199/please-add-the-ability-to-fold-blocks-of-code-in-questions-and-answers?noredirect=1#comment1294764_5199). I've casted a dup-close-vote by mistake and retracted it immediately. Several hours after that I got a comment from the confused user by "my" (actually auto-generated) comment.