# When a close-duplicate vote is retracted, the OP only banner and auto generated comment do not get removed

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments

This is similar to [this report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189788/when-retracting-a-close-vote-if-that-vote-led-to-a-comment-the-comment-is-not), but refers to the header that gets added to a post body.

See [here, on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/650099/i-dont-like-the-behavior-of-the-new-tab-page-in-google-chrome-29-0-1547-76-off) for an example. As of the time of posting, the duplicate vote was retracted, but both the header and the comment remain.

It appears to not show up when I'm logged out, but I continue to see it when logged in.

Comment: I see no header now.

Comment: @RobKennedy I still see it, even after clearing my browser's cache.

Comment: I have seen "possible duplicate" header on my own question when it was invisible when I logged out - maybe it works different for question author and that's why @RobKennedy can't see it and OP can?

Comment: We do cache the question page for a minute, including the header, so you may very well have seen the result of the cache in place.

Comment: @Oded Still there for me. Not a local cache either, since I cleared my cache and checked in two browsers.

Comment: @Oded that message is only shown to the OP so you won't see it there.

Comment: @waxeagle - Quite right. Forgot about that.

Comment: Is this still an open bug, or is it [meta-tag:status-bydesign]?

Comment: @doppelgreener open  bug, like most others. :/