# Questions sometimes have a "possible duplicate of" comment but no close vote?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, but I've seen it several times over the past few days. Occasionally there will be one of these comments under a question:

> possible duplicate of ...

But there are no close votes yet. I imagine this could be caused in the case where the close-voter retracted their close vote, but if so, shouldn't this also remove the comment if they were the only one? (This makes me wonder what should happen if someone else has voted in the meantime.)

I saw this today on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891276/how-to-trigger-and-find-status-of-sql-job-through-c) - however I voted to close, so it doesn't look like a repro right now, except that it should have two close votes if the commenter voted to close and so did I.

Not asking for anything to change, in fact I'm glad the comment was still there or I wouldn't have searched for a duplicate either, just wondering if there is any other reason this scenario would happen, other than the original close-voter retracting their close vote?

Comment: @psubsee2003 It was. There is a flag-to-close as duplicate on the question. But even if there weren't, there's nothing that prevents users from simply posting a comment in that format anyways...

Comment: @animuson I don't doubt they could, but I was assuming that it was automatically generated to begin with.  Obviously that is not a wise assumptions to make

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The person posting that comment only has 995 reputation. They can't cast close votes. They can, however, cast Close Flags, which create the same auto-comment, and also throw the question into the Close Votes Review Queue for 3Kers to look at.

Other possible cases:

- There's nothing stopping a person from simply making a comment in that format without actually voting or flagging to close.
- Such comments can occur from a normal close vote which has since [aged away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away), rather than being outright retracted, though that couldn't have happened this time, since the question is too new.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize the flag also created the auto-comment.

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that when I retracted the close vote, "possible duplicate" comment [What should we do when someone makes lots of unnecessary edits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330267/what-should-we-do-when-someone-makes-lots-of-unnecessary-edits?cb=1#comment376497_330267) wasn't removed.

I have to delete it manually.

I think that application should delete it if it was only single close vote.

Comment: True, there's already a feature request though: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189788/when-retracting-a-close-vote-if-that-vote-led-to-a-comment-the-comment-is-not