# Friendlier wording for automatic "possible duplicate" comment?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, wording, automatic-comments

While the duplicates handling is being changed, could the wording of the automatic "Possible duplicate of..." comment be changed? I know I can [edit this by hand afterwards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91741/can-i-change-the-possible-duplicate-of-comment), but maybe it would be nicer if the comment said something like: "This may already be answered by....", which

1. Sounds less harsh
2. Focuses on the ability to find the answer, rather than on the question's status
3. Is in line with the new rules which require dupe candidates to be already answered

Comment: 4. [Begins with a capital letter.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44528/capitalize-possible-in-the-automatically-inserted-comments-when-you-vote-to-cl?lq=1)

Comment: Oh man, is this "Summer of Love" coming up again? What's up with us being all friendly and nice? It's still winter and I'm grumpy dangit.

Comment: Duplicated question and "may have been answered" are different.

Comment: Love the current wording. Sounds like a compiler warning.