# "Possible duplicate"-comments removed after closure, even when edited

Tags: discussion, bug

I close-voted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568597/wcf-service-call-failed-415-unsupported-media-type) and edited the auto-generated comment after that.

Now the question is closed and the comment is removed. I [read here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46799/automatic-possible-duplicate-links-are-removed-even-if-the-question-isnt-clos/47208#comment114411_47208) on meta that such comments would stay if EditCount is not null, but that doesn't seem to be the case anymore since at least a few weeks.

Was this change intentional?

While on the subject: can the generated comment be made to look more like a proper sentence, especially with a capital P for Possible and a period on the end?

Comment: This has been reported before: [Don't delete comments with link to duplicate if they are modified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141414) and seems to jump back and forth between happening and not. There's a deleted answer (not mine) at that question which acknowledged the situation being fixed -- deleted because it isn't. It drives me fluffing crazy.

Comment: @Josh nice to see I'm not the only one scratching his head over why sometimes they disappear and sometimes they don't. Thanks. Given this is a duplicate, I will now remove this question.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of the edit count affecting comment removal.

When a question is closed as a duplicate, any comments containing a link to the closed question are removed. Additionally, such a comment is only generated when none exists in the comments already.

Those are the only two rules I've heard of concerning possible duplicate comments. The claim you are referring to is talking about *comment*, not question edits. This means that the comment is not deleted if it has been edited, but if the question was edited, it will still be deleted.

Comment: Found the claim, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46799/automatic-possible-duplicate-links-are-removed-even-if-the-question-isnt-clos/47208#comment114411_47208

Comment: @Code see revision

Comment: _"This means that the comment is not deleted if it has been edited"_ - and that is exactly what happened and what this question is about: I edited my comment yet it was still deleted.

Comment: Ah, weird. Then I don't have an answer.