# Do not hide the “possible duplicate” comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, duplicate-questions

I have just seen a questions that looks like a duplicate (already had 3 close votes) but as it has a lot of “upvoted” comments, the comment about the possible duplicate was hidden.

Comment: Related: Jeff wrote *"I did not consider ordering by time (should these be inserted with some fake time, or given fake upvotes so they sort to top?)"* after [implementing the auto-comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44173/autocomment-when-voting-to-close-as-duplicate/44529#44529).

Answer (score 6):

Since the close vote tally is visible, and there's obvious discussion on whether to close it or not, those that are interested are probably going to either check the comments, or click close and find out why people are voting to close.  Either way, it's easy to find for those that want to know, and I'm not sure than making the possible duplicate comment sticky is going to alter the situation, though it would be quite a bit of work.

Keep in mind that once that comment is added, the link will show up in the right hand sidebar under "Linked" so the link itself will still be visible, and anyone who has read through the question and still needs more info is likely to peruse the links and related questions in that sidebar.

Further, it causes a possible game scenario - that comment is editable by the person who first closed as duplicate for 5 minutes.  If I wanted my comment to be seen in a post with heavy discussion, I could mark a duplicate, make my comment sticky even though it's not highly voted, and then edit the comment with what I wanted to say, rather than the bogus possible duplicate notice.

Lastly, are there that many questions with this problem?  It seems that it would be relatively rare.

All things considered, I'm not convinced there is a strong need for this feature.

Comment: What about someone using the site for the **first time**, they are much more likely to know about the possible duplicate and view it if is the top comment.  However I agree this may be a rare problem and had not thought about someone using it to game the system.

Comment: @Ian If a question is in a state of flux, such that there is a discussion about closing it as a duplicate, then the person viewing the question simply came at a bad time.  If they are truly interested in the problem, they will click "more comments" and read everything.  If the question isn't closed as a duplicate, then it's fine that they didn't see the possible duplicate notice - It's shown under the heading "Linked" in the right hand sidebar if they are interested in the general topic, they will look at those links and related questions and poke around a bit.

Comment: The gaming could be prevented when [having Community posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44173/autocomment-when-voting-to-close-as-duplicate/44176#44176) the duplicate comment.

Comment: @Arjan There was a good reason why that wasn't done in the first place, when we asked for and received the "possible duplicate of..." comment auto-post.  I don't have time to find it right now, so I'm just going to tease you with the possibility that we might be stuck with it...