# Autocomment when voting to close as off topic

Tags: feature-request, comments, vote-to-close

Related: [Autocomment when voting to close as duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44173/autocomment-when-voting-to-close-as-duplicate)

I think the autocomment feature when voting to close as duplicate is fantastic. It helps the person who asked the question and alerts others to relevant questions.

It seems to me that a similar feature when voting to close as off topic would be equally helpful. Sometimes users voting to close don't take the time to alert the user that s/he may get better answers to the question on a different site. It's quite likely that such automatic comments would prompt the user to delete the question and repost it the other venue, thereby saving time and effort of moderators.

I'm thinking, just a little comment that reads "This question may be better suited for ...." If none of the 5 SE options is selected, then either no comment or a comment that simply reads "This question may be off topic for SO."

Comment: `It's quite likely that such automatic comments would prompt the user to delete the question and repost it the other venue, thereby saving time and effort of moderators.` - what usually happens at the moment (with manually entered comments) is the user tends to just re-post the question on the suggested site and abandon the original, *then* the original gets migrated, thus making *more* work for moderators as they have to dedupe and/or merge on the target site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I think a question is getting so few views that it might not reach the five votes to migrate it elsewhere, I'll flag it for moderator review, and say so in a comment -- if the user agrees, they too can flag for review, and *presto*, the question will soon find a new home. (At least, I always imagine two flags for migration will catch a diamond's eye that much quicker...)

Comment: Moderators should be human exception handlers. If you flag a question as off-topic, it doesn't mean that moderators will quickly migrate the question; it could be they wait for other users to vote the question as off-topic.