# Make it easier to agree with existing votes to close duplicates

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Choose the same question as others suggested when closing question as dup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1418/choose-the-same-question-as-others-suggested-when-closing-question-as-dup)

When arriving on a question thread that has a vote to close and a comment pointing to the duplicate, I generally follow the link to check and see if I agree, return back to the question and cast my vote to close with the same link -- unless I've seen another question similar before, in which case I look for that and cast my vote with that link instead.

The vote to close box is pretty cool, all you have to do is copy and paste the link.  However, a few times I've had something I didn't want to lose in my clipboard, so copy & pasting was out of the question, nothing for it but to hover over the link and pluck out the question number.  Which is also fine, if you're not using Chrome on a high resolution laptop.

In short, I was hoping we could have some sort of quick select that allows you to just click a button or icon next to an existing link and the id would be added to the input box ready to cast your vote.

Even better, I thought, might be to append a string to the link that identifies the visit to the duplicated question as a potential vote-to-close, and the SO orange bar appears with something like this:

> Question 123456 has been voted as a duplicate of this link, agree and *vote to close*?               **x**

Clicking the *vote to close* link would cast the vote and return you to the duplicate question.  This would save a bit of time, you wouldn't have to return to the duplicate and go through the vote-to-close process again.

Comment: Hmm, I searched and couldn't find the duplicate question.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we want it to be easier.  The current mechanism makes sure you can *see* what has been submitted by others as an original, but it also encourages you to *visit the page* if you want to vote to close as a duplicate.  I think it's important to make sure people do at least that much before casting a vote to close.

Comment: @Bill: The current mechanism doesn't force you to visit the page any more than the suggested one would, even with the current vote to close box you can just right click a link to copy the address and paste it straight into the box.  If anything, the latter of my suggestions would encourage visiting the possibly duplicated question more-so, with a simple click to agree with the vote to close being incentive to do so.

Comment: @Andy: Okay, maybe you're not *forced* to visit the page, but you are encouraged (and I've edited my answer).  I still don't think it needs to be *easier* for the same reason.